# Why can't the real set be an infinite reunion of closed sets?

Tags: general-topology

For homework, there was a question asking me to demonstrate that writing the Real set as: $\mathbb{R}$ = $\bigcup_n^\infty \mathbf{F_n}$, where $\mathbf{F_n}$ is a closed set, which does not contain an open set other than the empty set, is not possible. Frankly, I don't know where to start, as this construction of $\mathbb{R}$ seems perfectly fine.

Comment: It's because $\mathbb{R}$ is complete if i recall corectly. There's this theorem, i think it's from Baire

Comment: Baire Category Theorem.

Comment: I think I can't use this theorem, as it wasn't taught in my Real Analysis class. Also, Baire wasn't very clear to me, so I'm still kind of lost, not only in proof but in intuition. Thanks, though.

Comment: This basically *is* the Baire category theorem; the closure of a nonempty set is nonempty, so "$\mathbb{R}$ is not meager" is immediately equivalent to "$\mathbb{R}$ is not the union of countably many nowhere dense closed sets."

Comment: Yeah, guess I have to just prove Baire. Found it odd, since that was never even mentioned, so there was no way I could conclude so. Thanks!

Comment: See "Baire category theorem" in Wikipedia.